# Use associations to select different rows using scope

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js, model-associations

The scenario is that I have a table with 2 optional columns:
`Content(mandatory_column, optional_column1, optional2)`

Both of the optional columns are comments of different types. So, I want to store the comments in a different table as follows:

`Comment(comment_string, comment_type)`

When I create models for the above scenario, how should I define the associations?
I want to define two `hasOne` relationships as follows:

```
Content.hasOne(Comment, {
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    type: 'optional1'
  }
});

Content.hasOne(Comment, {
  constraints: false,
  scope: {
    type: 'optional2'
  }
});
```

However, with the above, I can't distinguish between them while referring to them via associations. For example `content.getComments()` will be ambiguous. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Use an alias `as: optionalComments` something like. Then  you can use `content.getOptionalComments()`